# are compiler and shell internal part of Unix?

Tags: unix

I had this question on my exam, now in diagrams I saw, we have : hardware, kernel, system call interface to the kernel, then (compilers, shells, sys.libs) and on top some applications. Does OS scope include only kernel, and everything else is just some additional functions we choose to install , or does a Unix OS include everything from the list I gave above?

Comment: Compilers, shells and libraries required by additionally installed applications would _not_ be considered part of the operating system.

Comment: my big dilemma is, I don't understand what they mean by unix, I mean, I must have compiler installed, how would things work, and there must be some kind of a shell , how else would we give instructions to os?

Comment: First you must not have a compiler installed to work with unixoid systems or with any operating system. A compiler is required to create software packages, even to create OS elements. But is is only required for creation, not for operation (usage). About the shell: certainly you do need a shell to work with the OS. Well that is not technically correct, but typically the case... Anyway, that does not mean that the shell is part of the OS. It is just typically installed and uses parts of the OS for its operation. It communicates with the OS via system calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, No. They are not an internal part of Unix but additional functionality to help make the Operating System more usable.

The OS scope applies primarily to the kernel only.

Whilst you need a compiler to build the kernel, you don't necessarily require one for the general day to day use of the system. Most operating systems don't ship the compiler by default and instead, the kernel and applications is built on one machine and then the resulting binarys are packaged and distributed either with the computer directly (Windows/Unix) or via the internet for others to download and install (Linux/BSD)

Likewise with the shell. Although all operating systems ship with a default one (`sh/bash/dash` on Linux|Unix systems, `Command Prompt/Powershell` on Windows), most general users can go their entire lives without using it.

Having said that, if you were to delete the shell, you'll almost certainly find your system won't boot up. This is because a lot of core start-up scripts rely on the shell to stop / start the services presenting interfaces between the user and the kernel.

In summary:

1. You need a compiler to build the kernel and applications but not for running the OS.
2. You need a shell to execute applications (which also includes the compiler)

Comment: So the point is : OS applies only to kernel, you need compiler to built kernel(like any other program) but compiler alone is not part of that program. Also, you need shell to interact with Kernel, but kernel(OS) won't be mad if you don't have one ?

Comment: That pretty much sums it up yes.

Answer (score 2):

OS have more or less 2 definitions :

1. academic : OS is soft for doing a abstraction layer between
   hardware and software
2. pragmatic : OS is soft that come with hardware when we buy it.

Compiler and shell don't enter in definition 1. It can be enter in definition 2.
And usually, users that are interesting by a compiler or a shell prefer to consider OS as asbtraction layer (academic definition).